# how can set style dynamically to component?

Tags: android

i have used getlayoutInflater method to style a button dynamically , but width,height and weight are not applied. how can solve this problem?

submenu is a horizantal linearlayout that my button is added to it dynamically.

```
in MainActivity : 
 award = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.btn_layout, null);
                    award.setId(R.id.award);
                    award.setText("---");
                    submenu.addView(award);

in inflater Layout :
<Button
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/subbtn"></Button>


in style.xml :
<style name="subbtn">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/selector</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: try `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subbtn);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add those with `LayoutParams` , before adding your View :

```
award.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
```

then :

```
submenu.addView(award);
```

Comment: @h3diyeh : plz see updated answer ,try adding another float parameter for setting weight.

Comment: it does'nt work , its error is :  Error:(87, 43) java: no suitable constructor found for LayoutParams(int,int,float)

Comment: i found the answer : `LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        button_params.weight = 0.3f;`